# Compare one number with numbers in array to find the smallest difference

Tags: php, arrays

I have:

```
$current_price = 100;
$array_price = array(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90, 140,150)
```

I want to compare the current price with the prices in the array, find the smallest abs difference and save the price from the array that has the smallest difference with the current price

```
$diff = '';
$diff_array=array();
foreach ($array_price as $value) {
    $diff = abs($current_pric - $value);
    $diff_array[] = $diff;
}
echo(min($diff_array) . "<br>");
```

In this case i can find the smallest difference but how i can save the price from the array that is connected with that smallest difference?

Comment: Find the index of `min($diff_array)`, and use that as the index into `$array_price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `$diff_array`. Just loop through the array testing whether the current difference is smaller than the smallest difference seen so far. If so, save the current difference and the current price in variables.

```
$smallest_element = $array_price[0];
$smallest_diff = abs($smallest_element - $current_price);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($array_price); $i++) {
    if (abs($array_price[$i] - $current_price) < $smallest_diff) {
        $smallest_diff = abs($array_price[$i] - $current_price);
        $smallest_element = $array_price[$i];
    }
}
echo "Closest price is $smallest_element\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem a little bit different.
Just save the value of the variable if it is lower than the saved one, and also keep the index of the array so you will have the index and the value of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this by using `array_walk` with `abs` and than in difference array use `min` & `array_search` retrieve the min array element which is the lower difference

```
$b = [];
array_walk($array_price, function(&$v,&$k) use ($current_price, &$b){
  $b[$v] = abs($current_price - $v);
});
echo 'Minimam array element is : '.array_search(min($b), $b).', which has difference : '.min($b);
```

Live working example : https://3v4l.org/QasYM